# why user’s session is not expired when the user’s Web browser is closed in Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django-sessions

I developed a website using Django. I have used the 'Remember me' checkbox on the login page. If a user logged in to their account/page without checking the 'Remember me' option, the session is not expiring when the browser is closed. I have used `request.session.set_expiry(0)`.But the session is not expiring.

When the user clicks the checkbox(Remember me option), the session works properly.

Also, I used the `user_passes_test` decorator in order to prevent the login user to go back to the login page and register page, etc.

views.py

```
@user_passes_test(user_is_not_logged_in, login_url='individual_homes', redirect_field_name=None)
def logins(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST['email']
        password = request.POST['password']
        remember_me = request.POST.get('remember')
        print(remember_me)
        user = authenticate(request, email=email, password=password)
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            if user.type == "individual":
                details = IndividualProfile.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id)
                if not details:
                    if not remember_me:
                        request.session.set_expiry(0)
                        return redirect("individual_home")
                    else:
                        request.session.set_expiry(30)
                        return redirect("individual_home")
                else:
                    if not remember_me:
                        request.session.set_expiry(0)
                        return redirect("individual_homes")
                    else:
                        request.session.set_expiry(30)
                        return redirect("individual_homes")
        else:
            return render(request, "login.html", {'msg': "Invalid Credentials"})
    return render(request, "login.html")
```

Can anyone suggest a solution for this.